# How can I add link class for Microsoft Office Word 2013 blog post?

Tags: microsoft-word, links

I need to somehow add class for created link in Microsoft Office 2013, because I would like to use a lightbox for the link. 
I don't want open the wp-admin area, I would like to solve this in one place, inside Word.

Here is a picture what I would like to do (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using actual html rather than allowing Office to convert the hyperlink for you? `<a class='fred' href='yoururl'>Link name</a>`

Comment: Actualy I looking for a WISHWING soloution, so when I make link, Can I add class for it.